# Volume of Hemisphere Puzzle

Tags: geometry

Here we have 3 hemispheres.
The volumes of which are; 
$$V_0 = y$$
$$V_1 = 15x$$
$$V_2 = 10x$$

Find $y$ and come up with a formula for finding $y$ with any values of $V_1$ and $V_2$.

[image]

---

This is my attempt at working it out but what I have at the very end looks very complicated and I wasn't expecting something like that.

$$V_0 = \left(\frac{2π}{3}\right)(r_0)^3 ∴ r_0 = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3V_0}{2\pi}}$$
$$V_1 = \left(\frac{2π}{3}\right)(r_1)^3 ∴ r_1 = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3V_1}{2\pi}}$$
$$V_2 = \left(\frac{2π}{3}\right)(r_2)^3 ∴ r_2 = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3V_2}{2\pi}}$$

Using Pythagoras' theorem we get;
       $$ (2r_0)^2 = (r_1+r_2)^2 + (r_1-r_2)^2$$
$$⇒       4(r_0)^2 = 2(r_1)^2 + 2(r_2)^2$$
$$⇒ 4\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{3V_0}{2\pi}}\right)^2 = 2\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{3V_1}{2\pi}}\right)^2 + 2\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{3V_2}{2\pi}}\right)^2$$
$$⇒      \sqrt[3]{\frac{3V_0}{2\pi}} = \left({\frac{\left({\frac{3V_1}{2\pi}}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}} + \left({\frac{3V_2}{2\pi}}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$⇒      V_0 = \left({\frac{2\pi}{3}}\right)\left({\frac{\left({\frac{3V_1}{2\pi}}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}} + \left({\frac{3V_2}{2\pi}}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{2}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Comment: Voting to reopen! :)

Comment: I am making the edits.

Comment: Another MathJax tip: To get parenthesis to match the height of tall things (like fractions, and your radicals with fractions inside), use `\left(...\right)`. For instance, `\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)` to get $$\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)$$

Comment: think I made those edits, wish I had just use that notation to begin with.

Comment: Good work! :) Now, because I can see things more clearly ... You seem to be using "$V_0 r$" to indicate the radius of the hemisphere with volume $V_0$; that's terribly confusing, since it looks like the product of the volume and $r$. Instead, call the radius "$r_0$". Likewise, use $r_1$ and $r_2$. (As a bonus, there'll be a bit of a reduction in visual clutter; things like "$(V_0r)^3$" will simply become "$r_0^3$".)

Comment: Now, about the actual math ... You seem to believe that the diameter of the $V_0$  hemisphere has as its endpoints the very tops of the other two hemispheres. If this is true, then the plane of the upper hemisphere will slice through the $V_1$ hemisphere. Is this what you intend? If so, then your Pythagorean relation among the radii is correct. However, I suspect that the plane of the upper hemisphere is supposed to be *tangent* to the lower hemispheres; in that case, there's more work to do, as described in Boshu's answer. Either way, describe the intended situation clearly in the question.

Comment: I see what you are saying and it is a false assumption I have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the given relations on $V_1$ and $V_2$ to get their respective radii. Having found the radii in terms of $x$, you need to find the length of the direct common chord between them. Draw the radii from the the centres $C_1$ and $C_2$ to the tangent $T$, note that they are perpendicular. Let them meet the tangent at $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively. Drop a perpendicular from $C_2$ to $C_1T_1$, let them meet at $X$. Then $C_1C_2X$ is a right angled triangle, $C_2XT_1T_2$ is a rectangle. Now use pythagorus' theorem to find the length of the tangent, which is the same as the diameter of the topmost hemisphere and equate with the area.

Comment: I have given this a go and posted an answer, think I got the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

$$V_0 = \left(\frac{2π}{3}\right)(r_0)^3 ∴ r_0 = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3V_0}{2\pi}}$$
$$V_1 = \left(\frac{2π}{3}\right)(r_1)^3 ∴ r_1 = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3V_1}{2\pi}}$$
$$V_2 = \left(\frac{2π}{3}\right)(r_2)^3 ∴ r_2 = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3V_2}{2\pi}}$$

Using Pythagoras' theorem we get;
$$(r_1+r_2)^2 = (2r_0)^2 + (r_1-r_2)^2$$
$$⇒(r_0)^2 = r_1r_2$$
$$⇒\left({\frac{3V_0}{2\pi}}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}} = {\frac{3V_1}{2\pi}}^{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{3V_2}{2\pi}}^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$⇒\left({\frac{3V_0}{2\pi}}\right)^2 = {\frac{9V_1V_2}{4\pi^2}}$$
$$⇒V_0^2 = V_1V_2$$

Now just sub in $V_1$ and $V_2$ respectively.